# Custom sorting on varchar field in mysql is possible?

Tags: php, mysql

I have one field named "priority" with type varchar(20) in my table, which can have these four values: show stopper, high, medium, low

Now, when I sort this with query "Select priority from issues order by priority" it results me:
1. High
2. Low
3. Medium
4. Show stopper

But I need this on following order:
1. Show stopper
2. High
3. Medium
4. Low

Please suggest me what can do in above written query to fetch the result in this order?
I know if I will change the varchar to enum, problem will be solved. But I can not change the field type due to some project concept restrictioans, so please tell me some other solution. Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you can you might want to look at restructuring your schema to put these values into a lookup table. You could then add a "priority order" field to each one to specify the ordering.

Comment: You should probably accept Dagon's answer...

Answer (score 4):

```
             ...
             ORDER BY CASE priority WHEN 'show stopper' THEN 1
             WHEN 'high' THEN 2
             WHEN 'medium' THEN 3
             WHEN 'low' THEN 4
             END
```

or

```
             ORDER BY FIELD(priority,'show stopper', 'high', 'medium', 'low');
```